# Cant access kubernetes service from another machine

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes

My goal is to access a certain kubernetes service deployed on my machine (cluster) from a machine outside the cluster (another machine). I am exposing these services using "Ingress" objects.
I have a single node-kubernetes cluster on which i have installed nginx-ingress controller, the external-IP for this is assigned by Metal-LB load-balancer.

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE

kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>          443/TCP          2d
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.105.168.2   192.168.1.240   8080:32622/TCP   46h
```

I am able to access the loadbalancer on my machine using the external-ip so produced. But cannot access this outside the cluster(machine)/ from another machine using the external-IP.
Using the external-IP in another machine results in a connection-timed out error.

nginx ingress-controller installed from kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.22.0/deploy/mandatory.yaml and exposed as a load-balancer type.

Configuration for metallb is given below:

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.240/28
```

PS: both the machines are on same network.

Comment: Hi riemann77, welcome to SF. You'll need to [edit your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1019586/edit) and include the details of how you tried to access the Ingress that shows you "cannot access this outside the cluster." There are many things that _could_ be wrong, but only showing the steps you have already tried will enable us to help you. Good luck

Comment: If its possible please share with us your configuration YAMLs. Also more details about both machines (one you can access and secon where you cannont), are they in some coroprate netowrk, did you set some firewall rules, etc.

Comment: @PjoterS  have added relevant configuration details

Comment: I need more information. It's Kubeadm cluster? What version of kubernetes and docker are you using. What is your CNI? Did you try [this](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/troubleshooting/)?